# Removing user from People Picker, by not deleting/disabled user in AD

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, administration, central-administration, people-picker

I have a question in regards with removing the user from people picker.

I'm using LDAP syntax filter **(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))** and is working properly, the user can't be found at the people picker when deleting/disabling the account from the **Active Directory**.

My problem is when i try to not delete/disable the account in Active Directory the user is appearing in the people picker when using the this link for my option https://www.sharepointfire.com/2013/10/remove-users-from-user-information-list/

Is there a way on how to remove the users from the people picker by not deleting/disabling the users from the AD?

FYI: I'm using **SharePoint Active Directory Import**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get this resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds weird and impossible to me .

The only way to remove a user from people picker is to remove that user from all below mentioned locations ,

a. Site collection user information list

b. User profile service application

c. Active directory

If the user is present in any of this the people picker is going to recognize the user.

Anyways what is your end goal , why do you want to remove a user from people picker ?

Comment: yash.. I have the opposite problem.  I upload content into a Knowledge Base and go to add the author from a people picker list, but the user has left the company and is no longer in Active Directory so I can't save the form.  Any advice?

Comment: thanks for that, my goal is to hide the selected user from the people picker by not disabling/deleting the user on AD. Because if i disable the user from AD he/she can no longer receive email, our exchange server is connected to AD. 
There is a user with the same name like **anders_smith@company.com** and **smith_anders@othercompany.com**, i would like to hide **smith_anders@othercompany.com** so that the other user can only select **anders_smith@company.com**. I can only hide the **@othercompany.com** by disabling **smith_anders@othercompany.com** from the AD.